# Example of objects and morphisms in h-TOP

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, examples-counterexamples, homotopy-theory

*I've started studying algebraic topology and I've come up with my first example of real category: the h-TOP category.
In order to understand it better, I've thought about an example, and I'd like to know whether it's correct or not.*

I start considering the objects $\mathbb{R}_*$ (which represents $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$) and $X = D^2 \sqcup D^2$ (the disjoint union of two unit disks, which I represent as a subspace of the real space: $(\{0\} \times D^2) \cup (\{1\} \times D^2) = \{ \vec{x}\ |\ x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 \leq 1,\ x_1 = 0, 1 \}$).

On the one hand, the set of morphisms from $\mathbb{R}_*$ to $X$ is precisely the one containing only $[a]$, $[b]$, $[c]$ and $[d]$, where
\begin{equation}
a(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} (0, 0, 0) && x < 0 \\ (1, 0, 0) && x > 0 \end{array} \right.
\textrm{,}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
b(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} (1, 0, 0) && x < 0 \\ (0, 0, 0) && x > 0 \end{array} \right.
\textrm{,}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
c(x) = (0, 0, 0)
\textrm{,}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
d(x) = (1, 0, 0)
\textrm{.}
\end{equation}

On the other hand, the set of morphisms from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}_*$ is precisely the one containing only $[e]$, $[f]$, $[g]$ and $[h]$, where
\begin{equation}
e(\vec{x}) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} -1 && x_1 = 0 \\ 1 && x_1 = 1 \end{array} \right.
\textrm{,}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
f(\vec{x}) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} 1 && x_1 = 0 \\ -1 && x_1 = 1 \end{array} \right.
\textrm{,}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
g(\vec{x}) = -1
\textrm{,}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
h(\vec{x}) = 1
\textrm{.}
\end{equation}

Notice that $[e] \circ [a] = \textrm{Id}_{\mathbb{R}_*}$, because
\begin{equation}
e \circ a = e\left( \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} (0, 0, 0) && x < 0 \\ (1, 0, 0) && x > 0 \end{array} \right. \right) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} -1 && x < 0 \\ 1 && x > 0 \end{array} \right.
\end{equation}
is homotopic to $\textrm{Id}_{\mathbb{R}_*}$.

Also, $[a] \circ [e] = \textrm{Id}_X$, because
\begin{equation}
a \circ e = a\left( \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} -1 && x_1 = 0 \\ 1 && x_1 = 1 \end{array} \right. \right) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} (0, 0, 0) && x_1 = 0 \\ (1, 0, 0) && x_1 = 1 \end{array} \right.
\end{equation}
is homotopic to $\textrm{Id}_X$.

From these last observations follows the fact that $[a]$ is an isomorphism between $\mathbb{R}_*$ and $X$ and hence that $\mathbb{R}_*$ and $X$ are homotopically equivalent.

*Please, point out EVERY mistake, and suggest other examples that allow me to understand the category h-TOP better.*

Comment: Is it not easier to show that both the obvious maps $X\rightarrow S^0\leftarrow\mathbb{R}_*$ are homotopy equivalences? You can take these maps to be the quotient maps which identify path-connected points. Now use the transitivity of the relation 'homotopy equivalent to'. i.e. the fact that homotopy equivalences become isomorphisms in $hTop$.

Comment: I'm trying to get intuition, that's why I listed the distinct morphisms.

Comment: You'll notice that I told you *exactly* what the maps were, and *exactly* how the spaces become homotopy equivalent: 'identify path-connected points'. I find this much more intuitive. It's difficult for me to see at a glance that this is what is happening with the maps you wrote down. You asked for suggestions to help you understand $hTop$, and my comment was merely that.

Comment: For two trivial examples, if $X$ is contractible then $Hom_{hTop}(X, Y)\cong \pi_0(Y)$ and if $Y$ is contractible then $Hom_{hTop}(X, Y)$ is a singleton. A classic non-trivial example is $Hom_{hTop}(S^1, S^1)$: if we're in the *pointed* homotopy category then this is by definition $\pi_1(S^1) \cong \mathbb{Z}$, where the homotopy class of a function is determined by its winding number, and if we are not in the pointed category then every continuous function is still homotopic to a pointed one and our $Hom$ set is still in bijection with $\mathbb{Z}$.